# Numberphile's "plastic number" video, question regarding "calipers" used

Tags: geometry, polynomials, golden-ratio

Sorry for the poor title, but this question is awkward.

Numberphile has a new video about the plastic number, and it demonstrates it with a set of calipers with 4 prongs.

https://youtu.be/PsGUEj4w9Cc

Towards the end of the video (11:10) , the guy remarked that there is a similar 3-pronged caliper that generates the golden ratio, but that "there is no way to do something similar with a 5-pronged caliper."

... why? It's by far the most interesting statement made in the video and they just say nothing at all and leave it at that.

Why can't something similar be done with a 5 pronged caliper?

Comment: If you make the gaps between the prongs $1, x, x^2, x^3$, the problem is that you need $x^4 = x+1$ and $x^7 = x^2 + x + 1$, which has no simultaneous solution: if $x^4 = x+1$, then $x^7 = x^3 + x + 1$. However, I'm not sure how to prove this can't be done by changing the order of the prongs or having other powers for the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

edit: Here's a [visual proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26FuL.png) for this instance. I should have taken the time to draw this out before my initial post, sorry.(end edit)

While I have not yet come up with a general proof, I did manage to find a 5-prong counterexample, so his claim is incorrect. My counterexample contains the following ratios:

first layer: x^5, x^6, x^7, x^3 /

second layer: x^3, x^4, x^2 /

third layer: x^2, x^1 /

fourth layer: x^0 /

where 1=x^2+x^3

I think it is safe to conjecture that it is not possible to create calipers with an arbitrarily-large number of prongs, and I suspect the upper bound is no higher than 6.

Comment: $x^7 + x^3\ne x^3$ nor any other power of $x$.

Comment: Sorry that my list was originally so hard to read. The relationship in question is x^7+x^3=x^2. Let me explain my reasoning: the rule x^2+x^3=1 is used to generate these relationships. We can multiply both sides of this equation by some further power of x and it still remains true, such that x^5+x^6=x^3, and x^6+x^7=x^4, and so on. Pairing these together, we can see that x^5+(x^6+x^7)=x^5+x^4=x^2 which is similar to our starting rule. However because addition is commutative, if we switch the parentheses, we should still get the same result; thus, (x^5+x^6)+x^7=x^3+x^7=x^2.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I hope this clears up your criticism?

Comment: There's still two problems here. The first is that the lengths are not all unique, which is the point of the exercise. The second is that the solution to $x^2 + x^3 = 1$ is not $(\sqrt{5}-1)/2$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Nowhere in OP's question does it say the intervals need to be unique. And the youtube video just says "the gaps between two dividers need to be a power of the same number."

You are however quite correct about the wrong solution, sorry. I've been working with a bunch of different generating rules and got confused which one was which. I believe everything is fixed now?

Comment: +1. Numberphile says (*emphasis* mine): "[T]he gap between [any two pins is] the power of one number. There's a [three-pin] version [for] the golden ratio [...]. There's no way to do that with five pins. *If you want a set of dividers where the jump between any two pins is a power of the same number*, then [the four-prong 'plastic ratio' scheme] is the best you can do." Your scheme, even with its repeated powers, contradicts the claim as stated. We can only speculate about whether the speaker *intended* something more specific (eg, *unique* powers); perhaps someone should just ask the guy. :)